# How to get records from pivot table in desc from controller to vue template

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-8

In my laravel vue project i tried to get data from pivot table in desc order and sent array to vue but the array displayed in asc .
i have two tables many to many relation
Posts
categories
post_category

this is the request in vue file

```
export default {
  components: {
    JetInputError,
    Multiselect,
  },
  props: ['all_categories'],
  data() {
    return {     
      posts:[]
    };
  },
  methods: {

    loadHomeData(){
            axios.get(route('home.data')).then(response => this.posts = response.data.posts);
        },
```

controller.php

```
$posts = $category->postHasCategories()->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')->get();
return response()->json([
        'posts' => $posts,
    ], 200);
```

when i print array in for loop in vue template the array display in asc order not desc

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `orderByDesc` :

```
  $posts = $category->postHasCategories()->orderByDesc('posts.created_at')->get();

  return response()->json([
    'posts' => $posts,
   ], 200);
```